# Java Making Immutable Subclasses

Tags: java, abstract-class, immutability

I have the following abstract class:

```
    public abstract class Client {

       final private String anonymousCilentID;
       final private String anonymousCilentFirstName;
       final private String anonymousCilentLastName;
       final private String gender;

            protected Client(String anonymousCilentID, String anonymousCilentFirstName, String anonymousCilentLastName, String gender) {
                this.anonymousCilentID = anonymousCilentID;
                this.anonymousCilentFirstName = anonymousCilentFirstName;
                this.anonymousCilentLastName = anonymousCilentLastName;
                this.gender = gender;
            }

        public String getAnonymousCilentID() {
            return anonymousCilentID;
        }

        public String getAnonymousCilentFirstName() {
            return anonymousCilentFirstName;
        }

        public String getAnonymousCilentLastName() {
            return anonymousCilentLastName;
        }

        public String getGender() {
            return gender;
        }
    }
```

and the following Subclass:

```
final public class AnonymousCilent extends Client {


   final private Date arrivalDate;
   final private String immStatus;
   final private Date registrationDate;
   final private String registrationSite;
   final private String siteName;
   final private String comments;



final public class AnonymousCilent extends Client {


   final private Date arrivalDate;
   final private String immStatus;
   final private Date registrationDate;
   final private String registrationSite;
   final private String siteName;
   final private String comments;

    public AnonymousCilent(String anonymousCilentID, String anonymousCilentFirstName, String anonymousCilentLastName, String gender, Date arrivalDate, String immStatus, Date registrationDate, String registrationSite, String siteName, String comments) {

        super(anonymousCilentID,anonymousCilentFirstName, anonymousCilentLastName, gender);

        this.arrivalDate = arrivalDate;
        this.immStatus = immStatus;
        this.registrationDate = registrationDate;
        this.registrationSite = registrationSite;
        this.siteName = siteName;
        this.comments = comments;
    }


    public Date getArrivalDate() {

        return new Date (arrivalDate.getTime());
    }

    public String getImmStatus() {
        return immStatus;
    }

    public Date getRegistrationDate() {
        return new Date (registrationDate.getTime());
    }

    public String getRegistrationSite() {
        return registrationSite;
    }

    public String getSiteName() {
        return siteName;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return comments;
    }
}
```

I need to create a subclass but I want to do what is the best practice when it comes to making immutable classes. I set my abstract constructor to protected, declared my variables private final/no setters. Is my subclass immutable? Have I done something in bad practice? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Your subclass is effectively mutable because it exposes a `Date`, which is mutable...

Comment: AH! I need defensive copying correct? Other than that, do you see any other problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your class `AnonymousCilent` is not immutable, because class `java.util.Date` is not immutable. I could do this:

```
AnonymousCilent object = ...;

// Modifies the Date object held by the AnonymousCilent object
object.getArrivalDate().setDate(23);
```

To prevent this, the getters for the Date objects should return copies of the member variables, for example:

```
public Date getArrivalDate() {
    // Return a copy of member variable arrivalDate
    return new Date(arrivalDate.getTime());
}
```

But it would be better to use the Java 8 `java.time` classes, which are immutable, instead of `java.util.Date`, or use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) if you're not using Java 8.

Comment: Except for the date variable, is everything else okay? Have I done what is best practice?

Comment: @Nexusfactor Yes, for the rest your class is OK.

Comment: @Nexusfactor You should call `getTime()`, not `getDate()`, on the `Date` objects you want to copy. With `getDate()` you will get incorrect results, see the [API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html).

Comment: Edit completed. Is this how you would create an immutable subclass? In a professional/real world scenario?

Comment: @Nexusfactor Yes, that is what a real immutable class should look like.